# Check Results Trend using NumPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, group-by

I have a Dataframe like mentioned below:

```
PROCESS_NO  PROCESS_NAME     RESULT_2    RESULT_3 
10254       AAA              4.40        46.67 
10254       AAA              4.45        48.33 
10254       AAA              4.50        50.00 
10254       AAA              4.45        48.33 
10254       AAA              4.50        50.00 
10255       BBB              4.50        50.00 
10255       BBB              4.50        50.00 
10254       AAA              4.45        48.33 
10254       AAA              4.45        48.33 
10254       AAA              4.45        48.33 
10255       BBB              4.50        51.60 
10255       BBB              4.50        52.80 
10255       BBB              4.50        56.80 
10255       BBB              4.50        51.70 
10255       BBB              4.46        57.90 
10255       BBB              4.44        52.00
```

I want to check if corresponding RESULT_2, RESULT_3 values are same or higher to previous 3 row values then assign True otherwise false in another column **group by PROCESS_NO, PROCESS NAME**.

I want my Result Dataframe like this.

```
PROCESS_NO  PROCESS NAME    RESULT_2    CHECK_2 RESULT_3    CHECK_2
10254       AAA             4.40        FALSE   46.67       FALSE 
10254       AAA             4.45        FALSE   48.33       FALSE 
10254       AAA             4.45        TRUE    48.33       TRUE
10254       AAA             4.45        TRUE    48.33       TRUE
10254       AAA             4.45        TRUE    48.33       TRUE
10254       AAA             4.50        TRUE    50.00       TRUE
10254       AAA             4.45        FALSE   48.33       FALSE
10254       AAA             4.50        TRUE    50.00       TRUE
10255       BBB             4.50        FALSE   50.00       FALSE
10255       BBB             4.50        FALSE   50.00       FALSE
10255       BBB             4.50        TRUE    51.60       TRUE
10255       BBB             4.50        TRUE    52.80       TRUE
10255       BBB             4.50        TRUE    56.80       TRUE
10255       BBB             4.50        TRUE    51.70       FALSE
10255       BBB             4.46        FALSE   57.90       TRUE
10255       BBB             4.44        FALSE   52.00       FALSE
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without using Numpy and in simplest way :

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[10254,'AAA',4.40,46.67],
        [10255,'BBB',4.50,50.00],
        [10255,'BBB',4.50,50.00],
        [10254,'AAA',4.45,48.33],
        [10254,'AAA',4.50,50.00],
        [10254,'AAA',1.50,10.00],]
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['PROCESS_NO','PROCESS NAME','RESULT_2','RESULT_3'])
dataframe['CHECK_2'] = 'FALSE'
dataframe['CHECK_3'] = 'FALSE'
check2_position = dataframe.columns.get_loc('CHECK_2')
check3_position = dataframe.columns.get_loc('CHECK_3')
for i in range(0,len(dataframe)):
    if i >= 3 :
        current_result2 = dataframe.iloc[i]['RESULT_2'];
        if(current_result2 >= dataframe.iloc[i-1]['RESULT_2'] or
           current_result2 >= dataframe.iloc[i-2]['RESULT_2'] or
           current_result2 >= dataframe.iloc[i-3]['RESULT_2'] ):
            dataframe.iat[i,check2_position] = 'TRUE'

        current_result3 = dataframe.iloc[i]['RESULT_3'];
        if(current_result3 >= dataframe.iloc[i-1]['RESULT_3'] or
           current_result3 >= dataframe.iloc[i-2]['RESULT_3'] or
           current_result3 >= dataframe.iloc[i-3]['RESULT_3'] ):
            dataframe.iat[i,check3_position] = 'TRUE'


print(dataframe)
```

result is as you want :

```
   PROCESS_NO PROCESS NAME  RESULT_2  RESULT_3 CHECK_2 CHECK_3
0       10254          AAA      4.40     46.67   FALSE   FALSE
1       10255          BBB      4.50     50.00   FALSE   FALSE
2       10255          BBB      4.50     50.00   FALSE   FALSE
3       10254          AAA      4.45     48.33    TRUE    TRUE
4       10254          AAA      4.50     50.00    TRUE    TRUE
5       10254          AAA      1.50     10.00   FALSE   FALSE
```

I hope this may help you.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
def greater_than(df_grp):
    df_grp['CHECK_2'] = df['RESULT_2'].rolling(3).apply(lambda x: all(x[2] >= i for i in x[:1]))
    df_grp['CHECK_3'] = df['RESULT_3'].rolling(3).apply(lambda x: all(x[2] >= i for i in x[:1]))
    df_grp[['CHECK_2','CHECK_3']] = df_grp[['CHECK_2','CHECK_3']].fillna(0).astype(int)
    return df_grp

result = df.groupby(['PROCESS_NO', 'PROCESS NAME']).apply(greater_than)
print(result)
```

**outputs**

```
    PROCESS_NO PROCESS NAME  RESULT_2  RESULT_3  CHECK_2  CHECK_3
0        10254          AAA      4.40     46.67        0        0
1        10255          BBB      4.50     50.00        0        0
2        10255          BBB      4.50     50.00        1        1
3        10254          AAA      4.45     48.33        0        0
4        10254          AAA      4.45     48.33        0        0
5        10254          AAA      4.45     48.33        1        1
6        10254          AAA      4.45     48.33        1        1
7        10254          AAA      4.50     50.00        1        1
8        10255          BBB      4.50     51.60        1        1
9        10255          BBB      4.50     52.80        1        1
10       10255          BBB      4.50     56.80        1        1
11       10255          BBB      4.50     51.70        1        0
12       10255          BBB      4.50     57.90        1        1
13       10255          BBB      4.50     52.00        1        1
14       10254          AAA      4.45     48.33        0        0
15       10254          AAA      4.50     50.00        1        0
```

**explaination**

- First apply groupby method on ['PROCESS_NO', 'PROCESS NAME']
- apply a custom function to group. This takes in the grouped dataframe as an argument
- Then you use pandas roll that draws a window around 3 values (centered at the last one)
- Call lambda function to check if all values are smaller than the previous ones (0 is 'FALSE' and 1 is 'TRUE')
- fillna as 0 for the start of the window that do not have 3 previous values

For more info see:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html

Comment: Sir, I want Output to be GrouBy PROCESS_NO & PROCESS. But with above operation I am not getting my desired result.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: I am using Py3.6. Error: FutureWarning: Currently, 'apply' passes the values as ndarrays to the applied function. In the future, this will change to passing it as Series objects. You need to specify 'raw=True' to keep the current behaviour, and you can pass 'raw=False' to silence this warning

Comment: Sir, Its still not matching with my desired output. Please check my result. 1st Two Rows for every PROCESS_NO & PROCESS will be Zero. Its not happening with above code.